# Weld use an injected class into another request

Tags: java, multithreading, cdi, code-injection, weld

I've a problem with injection and threadlocal.

Description :
I've a business class MyBusinessClass injected into my REST layer. Into this injected class i've added this countdown :

```
public class MyBusinessClass {
    private static long count = 0L;
    private long id = count ++;
}
```

And i've seen that some times the same instance is used in two requests, in two differents threads, so i've many bugs with injection.

Do you know why? It's a bug or a feature?

The context : Jboss AS 6.3 => Weld

Comment: So if you start your application and then two requests are made, then `count` is 2, is that your issue?

Comment: Not exactly. This bug is only some times (10% of requests when server is overloaded), but if we consider only two requests on error, the count will be "1" : Incremented with the first request and not incremented at the second because no new instance.